# Circular dependency when pushing view controllers

Tags: ios, typhoon

I have seen that the scope [TyphoonScopeObjectGraph](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopeobjectgraph-default) is useful for having circular dependencies, such a a controller and view, that has a delegate property pointing back to the controller.

So I tested this with the following scenario:

Controller A pushes Controller B which pushes Controller C that has a weak delegate pointing back to Controller A.

Controller C has a button that executes a method on this delegate.

I have seen that Typhoon instantiates Controller C, it properly sets Controller A as delegate, however when the button is pressed the delegate has been updated to nil.

This is the assembly code:

```
- (ViewControllerA *)viewControllerA {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ViewControllerA class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(name) with:@"Hello world!"];
    }];
}

- (ViewControllerC *)viewControllerC {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ViewControllerC class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(delegate) with:[self viewControllerA]];
    }];
}
```

This is ViewControllerC:

```
@interface ViewControllerC : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@implementation ViewControllerC

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate viewControllerDidTapButton:self];
}

@end
```

This is ViewControllerA:

```
@interface ViewControllerA ()<ViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewControllerA

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = self.name;
}

- (void)viewControllerDidTapButton:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Why is this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you please post your assembly code?

Comment: I have added sample code.

Comment: Thanks, I've answered. Sorry for the delay, we've had a tremendously busy week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TyphoonScopeObjectGraph creates a shared scope ***only during a call to assemble*** a particular definition. So if:

- View Controller A is built in one call.
- And then View Controller C is built, creating a dependency on View Controller A will create a new instance, which because of the weak reference, will subsequently go nil again.

If you want to create a circular dependency back to something that was built earlier you need either `TyphoonScopeSingleton` or `TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton`. The latter sounds appropriate in this case - for our own projects we sometimes use that scope for a shared 'context' object that should be discarded when no more references point to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I don't understand why should I create ViewControllerA with a singleton scope. ViewControllerA is created and then pushing B which later pushes C, so, someone must be retaining A. I mean, A is not deallocated, so, I don't know why it is being nil when executing the button action.

Comment: With `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph`, when Typhoon assembles ViewControllerC it will provide a new instance of View Controller A. Because ViewControllerC only holds a weak reference to this, it will then be niled, as nothing holds a strong reference. If you declare View Controller A with `TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton` (try it) it will work as you expect. You may then ask further questions to solidify your understanding.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was just trying that. It is working now as expected. Now, the question is: using `TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton`, who retains the ViewControllerA, Typhoon, Apple code or both?

Comment: With TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton its up to your code to hold a strong reference to the component being built. Examples: Giving it to a property with strong ownership, or pushing a Typhoon-built view controller onto a UINavigationController (which holds an array of all the VCs its presenting). The nice thing is, once nothing holds a strong reference, it will be deallocated. So, effectively, Typhoon does not retain components of scope weak singleton. (Behind the scenes it does, then uses some magic to release when required - not an important detail at this point).